# Add a custom link to hudson project page

Tags: python, continuous-integration, python-sphinx, hudson

I'm using Hudson to generate the documentation for a Python project using Sphinx. This generates HTML documentation in the folder project/_build/html, which I set up to be used as an build artifact. Now after running the job, I can navigate to the documentation by clicking on the "Artifacts" link, then on the folder, and then on the index.html file. That's a bit cumbersome so I would like to customize the project page so I can have a "View Documentation" link that takes me straight to the index.html file. Is there any way to do that with hudson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Project Description allows HTML, just edit it and place the link to your docs from the last successful build.

Comment: Ha! HTML in the Description. Easy :) No need to copy the files to another server, hudson will serve them just fine. I just had to link to "/job/my-job-name/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/path/to/sphinx/_build/html/index.html".

Comment: Yep, I thought that would be fine, I didn't have a hudson instance up and running at home to check.

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is closed, but I thought you could try this. You don't need a separate http server just to serve HTML documentation, artifact or not. You can use the plugin:
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

Comment: +1 That would have been my choice too. Haven't had the need to use it too, but toyed several times with the idea. If I read the documentation correctly, it even covers the saving part of the reports, so that they are not showing up as a artifact.

Comment: Yeah, it allows one to save older reports. I actually had to use it for some custom metrics reports that we do (Understand C++).

Comment: That looks like a useful plugin. But in my case, just letting Hudson serve my pages is fine, so adding a plugin (aka layer of complexity aka point of failure ;)) is just not neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

Get the sidelink plugin.  That let's you add a link to the ones that are on the left-hand side of the project page.